# Print multimap<string, vector<string>>?

Tags: c++, vector, multimap

I am trying to display the contents of a multimap with a string and a vector as key and value, respectively. I run into problems when I try to dislpay the contents of the vector (value in multimap). What I have done so far is:

```
    multimap<string, vector<string> > someMultimap;
    vector<string> someVector;
    someVector.push_back("test");
    someMultimap.insert(pair<string, vector<string> >("KEY", someVector));
    //So for it works fine...

    multimap <string, vector<string> >::iterator it;

    for (it = someMultimap.begin(); it != someMultimap.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << it->first << endl << endl << it->second << endl << endl;
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
                                          this is the problem, can´t do this with a vector(?)
    }
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for solving the problem?

Comment: A vector has multiple values.  How are these multiple values going to be displayed?  A space in-between, one value per line, etc.?

Comment: Do something besides trying to send a `std::vector<std::string>` directly to a `std::ostream&`. No such insertion operator exists last I checked. Your root question seems to be "How do I print a vector of string?". The multimap ultimately has nothing to do with that.

Comment: OT: Try using some of the new features of C++11 like `auto`, ranged-based for loops, initializer lists and emplace functions. Writing code like this becomes a much more pleasant experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a second loop for the vector.

```
multimap <string, vector<string> >::const_iterator it;

for (it = someMultimap.begin(); it != someMultimap.end(); ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << endl ;

    vector<string>::const_iterator itVec;
    for (itVec = it->second.begin(); itVec != it->second.end(); ++itVec)
    {
        cout << *itVec <<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

If you don't plan to modify any value you can make your iterators `const`

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great for me:)

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::copy` to output the vector's contents with a single function:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
//..
using namespace std;

for (it = someMultimap.begin(); it != someMultimap.end(); ++it)
{
   cout << it->first << "\n\n";
   copy(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
   cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the vector and print:

```c++
cout << it->first << endl << endl;
for (vector<string>::iterator j(it->second.begin()); j != it->second.end(); ++j)
    cout << *j << " ";
cout << endl << endl;
```

Also, don't use `std::endl`, it flushes on each call which can hinder performance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can define what it means to send a `std::vector` to a `std::ostream`.
Here's an example of one way to do it:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, std::vector<T> const& v) {
    for (auto&& e : v) {
        stream << e << ' ';
    }
    return stream;
}
```